# How to load all tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I use jquery-ui-tabs. If there several tabs opened, loads only selected tab, others loads when I select them. Couldn't you say, is there any method to load all of tabs?

*(Sorry fo my English)*

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have SEO requirements you can use iframe instead of ajax loading in all those tabs.

If you cannot use iFrame you can first of all load all the contenents of the pages with ajax when the page loads, then use them inside the tabs :D